# Motivation for Algorithmic Randomness Definition

Tags: kolmogorov-complexity, algorithmic-randomness

Wikipedia gives this definition for algorithmic randomness in terms of Kolmogorov complexity:

"Given a natural number c and a sequence w, we say that w is c-incompressible if $K(w) \geq |w|-c$.
An infinite sequence S is Martin-Löf random if and only if there is a constant c such that all of S's finite prefixes are c-incompressible."

One really intuitive definition would be that random infinite binary strings are those that can't be computed by any finite program, ie. they have infinite Kolmogorov complexity.

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this? Why is wikipedia's definition better than my naive one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kolmogorov complexity only applies to *finite* strings (which is why the word "prefix" is in the definition you quoted) so being an infinite binary string not computable by any finite program does not make that string have infinite Kolmogorov complexity; that notion is meaningless for an infinite string. It would make that string merely "non-computable", which is much weaker than what one (usually) means when one says "random".

For example, an infinite binary string could be non-computable, yet have 0s at all its even bits. Such a string would hardly be random since "random" is meant to (somewhat) capture the result of flipping a coin infinitely often. Of course if one flipped a coin infinitely often, the result would not be heads every other time. Agreed?

Comment: All makes sense - thank you for the response.

Comment: I would disagree about the coin.  With probability 1, the result would not be heads every other time, but that's still a possibility.  (Here I am obviously using "probability" in a physical sense, rather than in any algorithmic information sense, but it's the physical sense--or maybe a Bayesian sense--that's appropriate for the claim about the coin.)

Comment: @Mars I've always felt that we cannot say that it's a possibility because we cannot flip a coin infinitely often. Thus we also cannot say that it's an impossibility. (I said that, but was just allowing myself to be imprecise for the sake of the OPs understanding.) I would love to know what philosophers have to say about the matter.

Comment: @QuinnCulver, I understand, I think, and I have some related views.  (I think infinite sequences of tosses are irrelevant to science, and practical decisions, at least.)  Still, as soon as we allow counterfactuals about infinite sequences of trials, as your answer did, the fact that each sequence of outcomes is possible follows from the fact that it's an atom of the product space.  So the set of sequences with heads on every other trial is a set of possible outcomes, though it will turn out to have probability zero.

Comment: [Alan Hajek's article on "Interpretations of Probability"](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/) in the *Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy* is a good overview of work in philosophy of probability, although interesting developments in the last several years are merely mentioned in the last section.  On counterfactuals, the [Stanford Encyclopedia article](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/counterfactuals) is probably a good overview of philosophical work, although I haven't actually read it. David Lewis and Robert Stalnacker are seminal figures.

Comment: On second thought I am not so sure that the alternating-heads sequences have probability zero.  The uncomputable alternating-heads sequences should have probability 1, right?

Comment: @Mars With probability one there will be just as many heads in every other spot as tails.